# split last two words and filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, object

I would like to know how to filter array of values using javascript
How to seperate the arrays with 'provider-send' and 'provider-receive'

```
 var filterradio = id.filter(function(e){       
       return e.id.split("-")[0] == "provider-send"
    })
```

```
var id=["provider-send-credit-transfer", "provider-send-debit-fund","provider-receive-credit-transfer","provider-receive-debit-fund"]


Expected Output:
result_sn: ["provider-send-credit-transfer", "provider-send-debit-fund"]
result_rcn:["provider-receive-credit-transfer","provider-receive-debit-fund"]
```

Comment: If you split on *`-`* none of the elements would have one in it. Look at what `e.id.split("-")[0]` produces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```js
var id = [ "provider-send-credit-transfer", "provider-send-debit-fund","provider-receive-credit-transfer","provider-receive-debit-fund" ] ;

var result_sn = [] , result_rcn = [] ;

for( value of id ) {
  var twoWords = value.split('-',2).join('-') ;
  if ( twoWords === "provider-send" ) 
    result_sn.push( value ) ;
  else if ( twoWords === "provider-receive" )
    result_rcn.push( value ) ;
}

console.log( result_sn ) ;
console.log( result_rcn ) ;
```

Comment: You're not using `filter` properly, as you're not filtering anything from id, you should either use `reduce` or `for` or `forEach`,

Comment: @CodeManiac , Hi my friend, please see updated post.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be "provider-receive-..." and "provider-send..." then you can do the following to separate them

```
for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    if (id[i].split("provider-send-").length > 1) {
        result_sn.push(id[i]);
    } else if (id[i].split("provider-receive-").length > 1) {
        result_rcn.push(id[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: On side note: instead of spliting you can directly search for this value with `search`, or `startsWIth` or `includes`, +1

Answer (score 0):

Pass `2` as second parameter to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then again `join()` by `-`. The second parameter to `split()` specifies the max number of elements in the result array.

```js
var id=["provider-send-credit-transfer", "provider-send-debit-fund","provider-receive-credit-transfer","provider-receive-debit-fund"]

var filterradio = id.filter(function(id){    
    return id.split("-",2).join('-') === "provider-send"
})  
         
 console.log(filterradio)
```

Comment: Why not use `search` or `includes` or `startsWIth` instead of `split` and `join`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `reduce` instead of the `filter` as reduce is used to reduce the array size into a single returned element.
Here I am reducing the array into an object which has two keys `result_sn` and `result_rcn`.

```js
var id = ["provider-send-credit-transfer", "provider-send-debit-fund", "provider-receive-credit-transfer", "provider-receive-debit-fund"]


const result = id.reduce((obj, str) => {
  if (str.match(/^provider-send/g))
    obj['result_sn'].push(str);
  else
    obj['result_rcn'].push(str);
  return obj;
}, {
  'result_sn': [],
  'result_rcn': []
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You should add `^` to your regex, else it will match `some-provider-send` too, even though this is not case here, but it's good to consider IMO, anyways +1

Answer (score 0):

Using `.filter()` will require you to write 1 filter for every pattern you want to match have assigned to a variable.

Using `.reduce()` is recommended and is more easily expandable to support more patterns.

It may look intimidating at first but you're essentially using `accumulator` as the temporary variable that gets stored and brought forward to each iteration. And each iteration of the array will give you the current iterated value with `currentValue`.

I've added `something-else` as an example of adding new pattern.

```js
var id = [
  "provider-send-credit-transfer",
  "provider-send-debit-fund",
  "provider-receive-credit-transfer",
  "provider-receive-debit-fund",
  "something-else-credit-transfer",
  "something-else-debit-fund"
];

const {
  'provider-send': result_sn,
  'provider-receive': result_rcn,
  'something-else': result_ste
} = id.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  let prefix = currentValue.match(/^\w+-\w+/)[0];
  return {...accumulator, [prefix]: (accumulator[prefix] || []).concat(currentValue)}
}, {});

console.log(result_sn);
console.log(result_rcn);
console.log(result_ste);
```